# How to delete only the content of a file in Java?

Tags: java, file

How can I delete the content of a file in Java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this:

```
new RandomAccessFile(fileName).setLength(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new FileOutputStream(file, false).close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by opening the file [for writing and then truncating its content](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/file.html), the following example uses NIO:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

Path file = ...;

OutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(file.newOutputStream(TRUNCATE_EXISTING));
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

[Another way](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html): truncate just the last 20 bytes of the file:

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


RandomAccessFile file  = null; 
try { 
    file = new RandomAccessFile ("filename.ext","rw");
    // truncate 20 last bytes of filename.ext 
    file.setLength(file.length()-20); 
} catch (IOException x) { 
    System.err.println(x); 
} finally { 
    if (file != null) file.close(); 
}
```

Comment: hi,
    thanks for reply.Is there any way to partially delete the file content means starting from particular offset and count to delete?

Answer (score 1):

May problem is this leaves only the head I think and not the tail?

```
public static void truncateLogFile(String logFile) {
    FileChannel outChan = null;
    try {
        outChan = new FileOutputStream(logFile, true).getChannel();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Warning Logfile Not Found: " + logFile);
    }

    try {
        outChan.truncate(50);
        outChan.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Warning Logfile IO Exception: " + logFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file for writing, and save it. It delete the content of the file.

Comment: Did you mean, "Open the file for writing, and _close_ it"?

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        writer.print("");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

This code will remove the current contents of 'file' and set the length of file to 0.