# Does FileOutputStream truncate an existing file

Tags: java, file

Does

```
 final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

truncate the `file` if it already exists? Surprisingly, the [API documentation for Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileOutputStream.html) does not say. Nor does the [API documentation for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29). The [specification for the language itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) has nothing to say about the semantics of the `FileOutputStream` class.

I am aware that

```
 final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

causes appending to the file. But appending and truncating are not the only possibilities. If you write 100 bytes into a 1000 byte file, one possibility is that the final 900 bytes are left as they were.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14280385/545127

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2622206/545127

Answer (score 10):

#### `FileOutputStream` without the `append` option *does* truncate the file.

Note that `FileOutputStream` opens a *Stream*, not a random access file, so i guess it does make sense that it behaves that way, although i agree that the documentation could be more explicit about it.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @JohannesBittner for what? that it is a stream? it's right there in the name. additionally, the class doesn't offer any methods for truncating or moving a fp, if it wouldn't truncate on open the class would be useless.

Comment: I meant a source for the statement that FileOutputStream truncates the file without the append option. 

I'm not too confident in the semantics of a Stream in Java, in my understanding it could as well be that it writes to the file, and leaves the end of the file unmodified. I.e., for example, you write 200 bytes to an existing file that is 800 bytes long, resulting in the trailing 600 bytes being unmodified. I don't see why this wouldn't make sense per se.

Comment: @JohannesBittner you can easily try it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on Windows 2008 x86 and java 1.6.0_32-b05

I created 2 processes which wrote continually to the same file one 1Mb of the character 'b' and the other 4Mb of the character 'a'. Unless I used

```
out = new RandomAccessFile(which, "rw");
out.setLength(0);
out.getChannel().lock();
```

I found that a 3rd reader process could read what appeared to be a File which started with 1Mb of 'b's followed by 'a's

I found that writing first to a temporary file and then renaming it

```
File.renameTo
```

to the File also worked.

I would not depend on FileOuputStream on windows to truncate a file which may be being read by a second process...

- Not new FileOutputStream(file)
- Nor FileOutputStream(file, false) ( does not truncate )
- Nor

this;

```
out = new FileOutputStream(which, false);
out.getChannel().truncate(0);
out.getChannel().force(true);
```

However

```
out = new FileOutputStream(which, false);
out.getChannel().truncate(0);
out.getChannel().force(true);
out.getChannel().lock();
```

does work

Comment: "I would not depend on FileOuputStream on windows to truncate a file which may be being read by a second process" You might want to check your code for race conditions. Is the second process reading the file before the first process has `close()`-ed the file?

Comment: I hope so, that was the point. I was trying to ensure that the 2 writers processes left the file in a consistent state and the reader process could not read a half written file. I could share the code if I could upload it. Okay so you only asked about truncation, but my point was to see what gave consistent reads...

Answer (score -3):

`FileOutputStream` is meant to write binary data, which is most often overwritten.

If you are manipulating text data, you should better use a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileOutputStream.html) which has convenient `append` methods.