# Using FileChannel to write in the middle of binary files

Tags: java, file, file-writing, filechannel

I'm working on a project in Java with a large binary file from which I always want to read and write small fragments (for writing I'll fill the remainder with padding). Now, when reading a file with `InputStream` I can use the built-in `skip(long)` method to jump to the offset I'm interested in.

The problem arises when I try to write to the `OutputStream`. Since it is guaranteed to be a `FileOutputStream`, I can use methods like `getChannel()` to retrieve the stream's `FileChannel`, with which I can then jump to a specific offset before passing the stream on to the actual writing function.

I've written the following code snippet to demonstrate my problem. The `file` initially contains 6 bytes with ASCII values `"abcdef"` (excluding the quotation marks), so writing `'X'` to the 4th index should yield `"abcdXf"`.

```java
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
    fc.position(4L);

    fos.write('X');
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Problem is, when opening the resulting file with a hex editor, I instead get a 5-byte file with 4 zero bytes followed by the `'X'` I originally inserted into the file; which is what I wanted, only that now the file has shrunk and everything preceding the `'X'` has been set to 0.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in that piece of code and how to properly use `FileChannel` or other frameworks to achieve my goal?

Comment: See [**Does FileOutputStream truncate an existing file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387567/does-fileoutputstream-truncate-an-existing-file/45100363).  This is likely a duplicate of that question - I'll let others decide.  Also - file offsets are zero-based, so `fc.position(4L);` sets the position to the 5th byte.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, I didn't think of that yet. Apart from that, any ideas on why the preceding contents are nullified?